# Two iTunes accounts on one iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad

I have two iTunes accounts. One for company usage second - for personal needs. Both of these accounts are with separate credit card numbers (company cc an personal one). I would like to have applications that was bought on these accounts to be on one device (iPad/iPhone). Is it possible to manage in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You will be prompted to input the correct username and password for each new entry, Should be no problem at all :)

Just remember to log out with your personal/company account when buying new software and login with the correct account for the CC

Answer (score 0):

well unfortunately its not an easy thing, it requires you to sign off and sign in your different accounts each time! and its a headache. my recommendation is, prioritize the one you use most, and try to stick to that one, sense updates can be made from both accounts but installing new apps and purchases require password from the latest used account!

(if you are using iTunes match with either account, then throw in your towel)

good luck!